# Need to transfer the free volume group space to another volume group space

Tags: linux

I need to transfer the free volume group space to another volume group space ..

Is it possible ?

```
 VG                 #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg0_kwt_r3oql20      2   3   0 wz--n- 175.66g 992.00m
  vg_b00               6   3   0 wz--n-   1.52t  55.98g
  vg_s00               3   7   0 wz--n- 199.99g  29.99g
  vg_s01               7   1   0 wz--n-   1.46t      0
  vg_s02               6   1   0 wz--n-   2.29t 827.98g
```

Need to transfer the space from vg_s02 to vg_s01 .

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, it will not be possible easily, but if you have a physical volume in `vg_s02` that is not used in any logical volume (check with `pvs` and `lvs`), you could remove it with `vgreduce` from `vg_s02` and add it to `vg_s01` with `vgextend`.

Beyond that, you could try to resize file systems and logical volume sizes to free an entire physical volume, but I wouldn't even bother and either install a new disk or do a *backup / fiddle with the disks / restore* cycle.

A somewhat insane solution, which also might work in theory (*don't go there, therein lies madness*): Create a logical volume on `vg_s02` and add it as a physical volume to `vg_s01`. As I said, madness and I would rather shoot myself in the foot than actually do this. It's hard to understand and with every layer, you loose performance.

Comment: I would rather shoot myself in the ***HEAD*** than assign a logical volume as an underlying member of another volume group. This surely is madness...